# TypeError: 'coroutine' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol

Tags: sqlite, asynchronous, discord.py, python-asyncio, pycord

I'm trying to make a invite manager and I keep getting this error

```
  async with cursor.execute("SELECT id, uses FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ?", (member.guild.id,)) as cursor:
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Zacha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 378, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\SkriptsNet-Bot\modules\invites.py", line 48, in on_member_join
    async with cursor.execute("SELECT id, uses FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ?", (member.guild.id,)) as cursor:
TypeError: 'coroutine' object does not support the asynchronous context manager protocol
```

This is the code that I am currently using:

```
    # Member Join Event
        
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        async with aiosqlite.connect(self.DB) as db:
            async with db.cursor() as cursor:
                invites = await member.guild.invites()

                c = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d").split("-")
                c_y = int(c[0])
                c_m = int(c[1])
                c_d = int(c[2])

                async with cursor.execute("SELECT id, uses FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ?", (member.guild.id)) as cursor:
                    async for invite_id, old_uses in cursor:
                        for invite in invites:
                            if invite.id == invite_id and invite.uses - old_uses > 0:
                                if not (c_y == member.created_at.year and c_m == member.created_at.month and c_d - member.created_at.day < 7):
                                    print(invite.id)
                                    await cursor.execute("UPDATE invites SET uses = uses + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? AND id = ?", (invite.guild.id, invite.id))
                                    await cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO joined (guild_id, inviter_id, joiner_id) VALUES (?,?,?)", (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id, member.id))
                                    await cursor.execute("UPDATE totals SET normal = normal + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? AND inviter_id = ?", (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id))

                                else:
                                    await cursor.execute("UPDATE totals SET normal = normal + 1, fake = fake + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? and inviter_id = ?", (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id))

                                return
            await db.commit()
```

I tried to move the `cursor.execute("SELECT id, uses FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ?", (member.guild.id))` over into a variable then calling the variable, but it still did not work.

Any kind of suggestions or help would be helpful.

Comment: Not familiar with python concurrency. But a **coroutine** is a piece of code executed sequentially and switching its thread explicitly to another coroutine. The most elementary form of (non-preemptive) concurrency. So asynchronous it is not. I would look for functioning code examples.

Comment: The correct is `await cursor.execute(...)`

Comment: Replace innermost `async with cursor.execute(...) as cursor` with `cursor = await cursor.execute(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Member Join Event
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
    db = await aiosqlite.connect(self.DB)
    try:
        cursor = await db.cursor()
        try:
            invites = await member.guild.invites()

            c = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d").split("-")
            c_y = int(c[0])
            c_m = int(c[1])
            c_d = int(c[2])

            await cursor.execute("SELECT id, uses FROM invites WHERE guild_id = ?", (member.guild.id))
            async for invite_id, old_uses in cursor:
                for invite in invites:
                    if invite.id == invite_id and invite.uses - old_uses > 0:
                        if not (c_y == member.created_at.year and c_m == member.created_at.month and c_d - member.created_at.day < 7):
                            print(invite.id)
                            await cursor.execute("UPDATE invites SET uses = uses + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? AND id = ?", (invite.guild.id, invite.id))
                            await cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO joined (guild_id, inviter_id, joiner_id) VALUES (?,?,?)", (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id, member.id))
                            await cursor.execute("UPDATE totals SET normal = normal + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? AND inviter_id = ?", (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id))

                        else:
                            await cursor.execute("UPDATE totals SET normal = normal + 1, fake = fake + 1 WHERE guild_id = ? and inviter_id = ?", (invite.guild.id, invite.inviter.id))

                        return
        finally:
            await cursor.close()
    finally:
        await db.close()
    await db.commit()
```

The problem seems to be in the 'with' is not supported, something similar happened to me, I finally replaced it with a finally, this code will close the connection no matter what happens (remember that the finally is RAII and always can be executed), additionally you could place a Except with a rollback.